# php google app engine uploading files on local dev server

Tags: php, google-app-engine

On my local google app engine server (1.9.0) (PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.7) I always get `message/external-body` as mime type for uploaded files and the `tmp_name` does not have gs:// wrapper as it is supposed to . E.g:

```
[type] => message/external-body [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpFbTDzF
```

Where it should be (as on the production app engine):

```
[type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => gs://coscms-bucket/L2FwcGhvc3Rpbmcy...
```

Files are uploaded local, but it is just difficult to test it, when you don't get the right file names (gs://).

When deployed I get the correct mime type for uploaded files. Here is my test script:

```
<?php

use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$bucket = 'coscms-bucket';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {  
    print_r($_FILES);
}


$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => $bucket ];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/test.php', $options);
?>
<form action="<?php echo $upload_url?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
Files to upload: <br>
<input type="file" name="uploaded_files" size="40">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're working an a php-cgi binary to distribute with the linux SDK that will fix this problem.

Until then if you can test on mac or windows it'll work correctly in the development environment.

Comment: Two years have passed, the current version is 1.9.35 and the problem still persists. Any update?

Comment: Not exactly the out-of-the-box-google-product-solution I was hoping for. In any case I already switched to running the server under Windows. Thanks.

Comment: I am using the compiled extension when I run the dev_appserver.py but I am still seeing this behaviour, any leads?