# Google App Engine "Fake" Dev Uploads

Tags: php, python, wordpress, google-app-engine, file-upload

I'm using Google App Engine to develop a project based upon WordPress.

When I upload a file using the default media uploader, I get a corrupt image. Instead of the image contents being the file I uploaded, they are akin to:

```
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 816567
Content-MD5: NzAxZDY5YmRkN2ZlYzMyNmYxMGYzNTUxNmY5MzcyODk=
X-AppEngine-Cloud-Storage-Object: /gs/bucket-name/fake-YNmYY5YfmzAxRkY5MzcyOM==
content-disposition: form-data; name="async-upload"; filename="the_filename_of_the_file_i_uploaded.png"
X-AppEngine-Upload-Creation: 2014-08-08 12:00:00.000000
```

When I run the following in the interactive console:

```
print_r(file_get_contents("gs://bucket-name/fake-YNmYY5YfmzAxRkY5MzcyOM=="));
```

...The contents of the png file comes out.

What's going on?

In case it helps, to start the App Engine server, I run:

```
dev_appserver.py app-dev/app.yaml --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi
```

The Wordpress installation is running the Google App Engine plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a symptom of this problem:

[php google app engine uploading files on local dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197580/php-google-app-engine-uploading-files-on-local-dev-server)

The dev server puts uploads in `/tmp/` (like PHP normally does) instead of converting the upload to a `gs://` file